# Using difference of sentences as concatenation for sentence similarity task

Tags: natural-language, similarities

MT-DNN and SentenceBERT concatenate sentences with their difference for sentence similarity task (i.e. $[u; v; u-v]$). However, I can not find any sources, backgrounds or experiment results for concatenation of the sentences and their difference. Isn't just using $u$ and $v$ enough? Does anyone have a source or background of why they use the difference of the sentences?